# Not able to decompress DES3 encrypted data using Gzip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

While porting python2 code to python3, we're facing an issue in the gzip section of the code that compresses a DES3 encrypted stream.

Below is the code for encrypting data in DES3 and then writing to the gzip file:

```
def createEncryptedFile(key, enc_iv, path):
    checksum_generation = 'ciphertext'
    tmp_fd = open(path, 'w')
    encrypted_stream = utils.DES3Cipher(tmp_fd, key, enc_iv, checksum_generation)
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=encrypted_stream, mode='w') as fo:
        fo.write(bytes('Testing Data For Gzip', 'latin-1'))
    encrypted_stream.close()
    tmp_fd.close()
```

Below is the code for decrypting and unzipping the contents:

```
def decryptFile(key, enc_iv, path):
    update_size = os.path.getsize(path)
    with open(path, 'r') as update_file:
        decrypted_data = ''.join(utils.decrypt_des3_cbc_stream(update_file, update_size, key, enc_iv))
        inner_data = io.BytesIO(decrypted_data.encode('latin-1'))
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inner_data, mode='rb') as fo:
            print("The unzipped data: ", fo.read())
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  print("The unzipped data: ", fo.read())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/gzip.py", line 463, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/gzip.py", line 411, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'\x08\x08')
```

I've tested the DES3 encryption/ decryption methods separately and have ruled out the possibility of error there.

The error seems to be in the gzip section, any ideas ?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but I'm curious why you're compressing cipher text.  It shouldn't be compressible.

Comment: you may want to save all intermediate data (before compression, after compression, after encryption, after decryption etc) to the disk and compare these files to see where it diverges in version 3 and in version 2

Answer (score 0):

Your `open` calls should be in binary mode ie `open(path, "rb")` or `open(path, "wb")`, there's a posibility that Pythons decoding the files wrong in text mode.

```
        decrypted_data = ''.join(utils.decrypt_des3_cbc_stream(update_file, update_size, key, enc_iv))
        inner_data = io.BytesIO(decrypted_data.encode('latin-1'))
```

This doesn't look right either, I'm not sure how your decrypting the stream in `utils.decrypt_des3_cbc_stream` but it should be returning `bytes` not `str`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, if I open the file in "rb" mode, then I'm facing error while decrypting the block:


```
cipher.decrypt(block)
```

```
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 8 in length
```

That's why I'm need to open that file in r mode and then encode the block in latin-1 before decrypting it:

```
 cipher.decrypt(block.encode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: `utils.DES3Cipher` is taking a `str` input and producing a `bytes` output, however `utils.decrypt_des3_cbc_stream` is taking a `str` input and producing and `str` output. Your encryption and decryption methods are not generating like for like data. Your encryption side is fine, but your decryption side should only convert from bytes to str at the very end after decryption unzipping not in the middle of the process.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for us:

```
import Crypto.Cipher.DES3
import random
import hexdump
import gzip
import updater.utils
import io as StringIO

input_string = b"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

key = ''.join([chr(random.randrange(255)) for x in range(0, 24)]).encode('latin-1')
iv = ''.join([chr(random.randrange(255)) for x in range(0, 8)]).encode('latin-1')

bytes_obj = StringIO.BytesIO()
encrypted_stream = updater.utils.DES3Cipher(bytes_obj, key, iv)
encrypted_stream.write(input_string)
encrypted_stream.close()

with gzip.open('./des3__new_file', 'wb') as f:
    bytes_obj.seek(0)
    f.write(bytes_obj.read())

new_bytes_obj = StringIO.BytesIO()

with gzip.open('./des3__new_file', 'rb') as f:
    new_bytes_obj.write(f.read())
    new_bytes_obj.seek(0)
    decrypted_data = ''.join(updater.utils.decrypt_des3_cbc_stream(new_bytes_obj, new_bytes_obj.getbuffer().nbytes, key, iv))
    new_bytes_obj.close()
```